# TailwindCSS: Horizontal text overflow

Tags: tailwind-css

My website has some basic `<p>` tags with some text content inside. However, I just discovered that long text with no whitespaces/breaks overflows out-of-bounds horizontally. I've tried using `overflow-wrap` and `break-words` tailwind classes on the `p` tag but it didn't help. Any clues to fix this will be appreciated.

Steps to reproduce–go to my [website](https://www.sanchayjaveria.com/blog/tl1NKVOCorQPPtqhTNcP), view in responsive mode or reduce browser width to mobile. You should see the URL in the comment overflowing out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Applying `overflow-wrap: break-words` to the `<p>` element that contains the long URL seems to work:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://rsms.me/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:600&amp;display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&amp;display=swap">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="__next">
    <main class="flex-1 overflow-y-visible"><button type="button" class="flex lg:hidden absolute top-0 right-0 z-40 flex-col h-12 w-12 justify-center items-center group mt-4 mr-4"><div class="h-0.5 w-6 my-1 bg-gray-800 transition ease transform duration-300 opacity-50 group-hover:opacity-100"></div><div class="h-0.5 w-6 my-1 bg-gray-800 transition ease transform duration-300 opacity-50 group-hover:opacity-100"></div><div class="h-0.5 w-6 my-1 bg-gray-800 transition ease transform duration-300 opacity-50 group-hover:opacity-100"></div></button>
      <div class="fixed z-10 w-full text-2xl font-light flex flex-col justify-center hidden">
        <div class="bg-white flex flex-col min-h-screen items-center py-8" aria-label="mobile">
          <ul class="mt-20 list-none">
            <li class="w-full text-center py-8 hover:text-black transition-colors duration-300"><a href="/">About</a></li>
            <li class="w-full text-center py-8 hover:text-black transition-colors duration-300"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="w-full text-center py-8 hover:text-black transition-colors duration-300"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="flex fixed bottom-8">
            <div class="text-sm mt-2 text-gray-500"><a href="/terms">Terms</a> &amp; <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-8 py-12">
        <div class="hidden lg:grid grid-cols-3 items-center">
          <div class="col-span-1"></div>
          <div class="col-span-1 flex justify-center">
            <ul class="flex list-none">
              <li class="mr-6 hover:text-black transition-colors duration-300"><a href="/">About</a></li>
              <li class="mr-6 hover:text-black transition-colors duration-300"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="mr-6 hover:text-black transition-colors duration-300"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-span-1 flex justify-center"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-xl md:max-w-2xl lg:pt-24">
          <div class="font-light text-sm mt-16">
            <p class="text-black">(THRX) Theseus Pharmaceuticals Explores Strategic Alternatives</p>
            <p class="mt-5 italic">Thu Nov 16 2023
              <!-- --><span class="mr-1 ml-1">/</span>
              <!-- -->1
              <!-- -->minute read</p>
            <div class="mt-5 space-y-3">
              <div>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>Theseus Pharmaceuticals ($139M market-cap) is a company focused on improving the lives of cancer patients through the discovery, development and commercialization of transformative targeted therapies.</p>
                <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                <p>Earlier this week, <a class="text-black duration-200 hover:no-underline underline after:content-['_↗']" href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1745020/000174502023000073/thrx-20231113xexx991.htm">they announced</a> that the company
                  is exploring strategic alternatives. As part of this, they are laying off 72% of the workforce while retaining the head of R&amp;D, William C. Shakespeare in a consulting capacity. Note that Mr. William will not receive any salary but
                  his grant will vest as usual till the termination of his consulting contract. Based on <a class="text-black duration-200 hover:no-underline underline after:content-['_↗']" href="https://www.bamsec.com/filing/174502023000060?cik=1745020">the most recent filing</a>,
                  it appears that he owns 639,408 shares worth around $2M, so he seems well incentivized to be aligned with the common shareholders.</p>
                <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                <p>From OpenInsider, it also looks like the company has good institutional ownership, with Orbimed Advisors LLC owning roughly 40% of the company. What’s also interesting is that the company has a very clean balance sheet with very minimal
                  debt. This is the rough back-of-the-envelope liquidation value I got to:</p>
                <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://lh7-us.googleusercontent.com/u5-74AE9wxS309O03HIe-NE_2xBoS6VIMWg5EFuHlKe-fN--v84ZvZwVEmUcYjFLnqyMKWKBSEsm5X5YRO51yto3Dw5VzjADyN5_-jBMk4VfmgQ4BpbnWU8eZAqYYxqO2R0Gjtp4Fbn9tnmNmQOUo_g"
                    width="418" height="213"></p>
                <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                <p>Note that I’ve marked down the IP to 0 but there might be some more juice to squeeze from potential sale of their IPs.</p>
                <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
                <p>Disclosure: I own shares of THRX</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex mt-12"><span class="mr-2">Labels:</span><span class="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-xs px-3 py-1 duration-200 rounded-full mr-2"><a href="/blog/labels/4fotMpQdzMFCNBRshX0T">failed biotech</a></span><span class="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-xs px-3 py-1 duration-200 rounded-full mr-2"><a href="/blog/labels/WEz7Qnk5qyn8LZcf7NVL">investing</a></span></div>
          <div class="space-y-3 mt-8">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center"><span>1 comment(s)</span>
              <div class="flex items-center"><span></span><span class="mr-2 ml-2"></span><button type="button" class="transition-colors duration-300 " tabindex="0"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Like</span></button></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <article class="mt-8">
                <footer>
                  <div class="flex items-center">
                    <p class="inline-flex items-center mr-3 text-sm text-gray-900">Sanchay</p>
                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-600">Nov 24, 2023, 11:16 PM</p>
                  </div>
                </footer>
                <p class="mt-2 break-words">13D filed by Tang, purchased $10M worth of stock: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1191935/000121465923015548/d1124230sc13d.htm "On behalf of Concentra Biosciences, LLC, I am pleased to submit this non-binding proposal to acquire
                  100% of the equity of Theseus Pharmaceuticals, Inc. for $3.80 per share in cash, plus a contingent value right (“CVR”) representing the right to receive 80% of the net proceeds payable from any license or disposition of Theseus Pharmaceuticals’
                  programs (the “CVR Products”). We applaud your decision to preserve capital and pursue a strategic transaction with the objective of maximizing value for shareholders. We hope that you find that our proposal meets this objective."</p>
                <div class="flex mt-2 items-center"><button type="button" tabindex="0" class="font-light bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-sm px-4 py-2 duration-300 rounded-full ml-2">Reply</button></div>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center flex justify-end"></div>
            <div class="flex items-center">
              <div class="relative w-full"><textarea id="post" rows="1" class="overlay-textarea focus:outline-none  font-light resize-none block w-full p-2.5 border-b border-white focus:border-gray-600 mt-2 placeholder-gray-400" placeholder="Write a comment"></textarea></div>
              <button
                type="button" class="font-light bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-sm px-4 py-2 duration-300 rounded-full ml-2">Post</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Consider checking you have:

- Applied it to the correct element.
- Ran a Tailwind compilation after adding the class.
- The file that would contain the `break-words` class is covered by the `content` file globs.